# openssl unable to pass -config and -signkey options in the same command

Tags: certificate, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509, certificate-signing-request

I am attempting to generate a self-signed certificate with my custom config file for openssl. However, the options -config and -signkey are generating errors as below when used in the same command.

**command attempt 1:**

```
openssl req -x509 -config my_ssl.cnf \
        -in my_new.csr -signkey my_private_key.pem \
        -out my_new_crt.pem -days 3650 -sha256 \
        -extfile my_V3.ext
```

**Error message:**

```
req: Unrecognized flag signkey
req: Use -help for summary.
```

**Command Attempt 2:**

```
openssl x509 -req -config my_ssl.cnf \
        -in my_new.csr -signkey my_private_key.pem \
        -out my_new_crt.pem -days 3650 -sha256 \
        -extfile my_V3.ext
```

**Error Message:**

```
x509: Unrecognized flag config
x509: Use -help for summary.
```

What is going wrong in the above commands? And how can I pass both the -config and -signkey options together in the same command?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing - there's no `-config` option in `x509` and no `-signkey` option for `req`.

[man x509](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-x509.html)

[man req](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-req.html)